# increment operation in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have the following assembly code:

```
segment      .data
     sayi db 1

segment      .text
     global _start

_start: 

     mov ecx, sayi
     inc ecx
     mov [sayi], ecx

     mov eax, 4             ;system call number for output(sys_write)
     mov ebx, 1             ;default output device
     mov ecx, sayi          ;message to write
     mov edx, 4             ;message length   
     int 0x80               ;call kernel

     mov eax,1              ;The system call for exit (sys_exit)
     mov ebx,0              ;Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
     int 0x80               ;call kernel
```

I just try to increment a number and print it. This compiles successfully, but doesn't print anything to screen. What am I missing here?

Comment: Doesn't `sys_write` expect to be handed a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

```
 mov ecx, sayi
 inc ecx
 mov [sayi], ecx
```

The first line will copy the address of `sayi` into `ecx`, not the value at `sayi`. To get the value you would write `mov ecx,[sayi]`.
Another issue is that you've only reserved a single byte of space at `sayi`
, but you're trying to access it as if it was a `dword` (4 bytes). To reserve a `dword` you should use `dd` instead of `db`.

Then there's the problem with your printing. The `sys_write` syscall prints whatever `ecx` points to as a sequence of characters. It doesn't do any conversion from integers to strings, so that's something you'll have to do yourself.
Here's an example NASM implementation of doing such a conversion that I wrote for an earlier question:

```
; Input:
; EAX = integer value to convert
; ESI = pointer to buffer to store the string in (must have room for at least 10 bytes)
; Output:
; EAX = pointer to the first character of the generated string
int_to_string:
  add esi,9
  mov byte [esi],0

  mov ebx,10         
.next_digit:
  xor edx,edx         ; Clear edx prior to dividing edx:eax by ebx
  div ebx             ; eax /= 10
  add dl,'0'          ; Convert the remainder to ASCII 
  dec esi             ; store characters in reverse order
  mov [esi],dl
  test eax,eax            
  jnz .next_digit     ; Repeat until eax==0
  mov eax,esi
  ret
```

Alternatively, a number in the range 0..9 can be converted to a digit by simply adding `'0'` to it, and then printed with `sys_write` by placing the address of the digit in `ecx` and a `1` in `edx`.

Comment: i just need to increment a digit. a byte should be enough for that. speaking about chars, i guess i don't need a number conversion here, as '0' incremented by one is '1' anyway, right?

Comment: If you want to keep your variable a byte you need to access it as a byte, e.g. `mov cl,[sayi]`. I don't see any `'0'` or `'1'` in your code, but you could certainly convert a number in the range 0..9 to its corresponding character by adding `'0'` to it.

Comment: i resolved the issue by @Damien_The_Unbeliever 's comment, but thanks for your effort. writing assembly as a starter is nasty :)

Comment: The part about `sys_write` expecting a string address is already covered in my answer: _"The `sys_write` syscall prints whatever `ecx` points to as a sequence of characters. It doesn't do any conversion from integers to strings, so that's something you'll have to do yourself."_